# Actionbar Tabs icon with ninepatch not works

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, nine-patch

Can I put a ninePatch image in tabs and resize this automatically? I'll try this, but it doesn't works :() When the tab height/width is greather than the image tab height/width, the image doesn't resize me.

A visual sample here --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVD00.png

I'll want the tab icon user image would fill all tab space free, using the ninePatch. Is it possible?

I've an actionbar with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS. In each tab, I put a 9-patch image(size of this: width=40xheight=50).

In MainActivity:

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_one));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_two));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_three));
```

For example, tab_one_layout (I've put red background for visually identify the layout dimension int tab. The dimension is the same than the tab_one.9.png image):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageTabOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_one" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Where @drawable/tab_one" is a tab_one.9.png

My Styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.myapp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_compat_height</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionbar_compat_height</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```